# In Ruby, how do I replace an element in an array with potentially multiple elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, replace

Using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings.  How do I replace one element in an array with potentially multiple elements?  I have

```
phrases[index] = tokens
```

However tokens is an array and right now this results in a phrases array with strings and an array ...

```
["abc", ["a", "b"], "123"]
```

If tokens is ["a", "b"] and index is 1, I would like teh result to be

```
["abc", "a", "b", "123"]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `start` and `length` with [`Array#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D); replaces a sub-array from the `start` index for `length` elements

or specify `range`; replaces a sub-array specified by the range of indices.

```
phrases = ["abc", "token_placeholder", "123"]
tokens = ["a", "b"]
index = 1
phrases[index, 1] = tokens
#       ^^^^^^^^^ ------------------ start and length

# OR phrases[index..index] = tokens
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ -------------- range

phrases # => ["abc", "a", "b", "123"]
```

Comment: Nice, I never cam across this syntax. Good to know!

Comment: It's `ary[start, length] = obj or other_ary or nil` in the [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
arr = ["abc", ["a", "b"], "123"]

arr.flat_map(&:itself)
  #=> ["abc", "a", "b", "123"]
```

`arr` is unchanged. To modify `arr` in place,

```
arr.replace(arr.flat_map(&:itself))
  #=> ["abc", "a", "b", "123"] 
arr
  #=> ["abc", "a", "b", "123"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Flat map would be a better way to go about it, it maps (transforms) then flattens the list to a single array. Say we wanted to add two elements for even numbers:

```
(1..10).flat_map { |i| i.even? ? [i, i**2] : i }
```

It would return:

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 16, 5, 6, 36, 7, 8, 64, 9, 10, 100]
```

As compared to map which would return:

```
[1, [2, 4], 3, [4, 16], 5, [6, 36], 7, [8, 64], 9, [10, 100]]
```